# Copies of cloned network do not train when placed in larger module

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I want to train a small network module by cloning it and placing it in a few different larger networks. But when I place it one such a context, it's parameters are not updated during training. Below is a small example that shows the problem.

I make the the small primitive network like this:

```
function mkPrimitive()
    local inp  = nn.Linear(2, 2)()
    local outp = nn.Tanh()(nn.Linear(2, 2)(nn.Tanh()(inp)))
    return nn.gModule({inp}, {outp})
end
prim = mkPrimitive()
```

Then I put it into a bigger network, called `toTrain`, like this:

```
function mkNet()
    local fst = prim:clone('weight', 'gradWeight', 'bias', 'gradBias')()
    local snd = prim:clone('weight', 'gradWeight', 'bias', 'gradBias')(fst)
    return nn.gModule({fst}, {snd})
end

toTrain = mkNet()
```

Then I train the larger network, and print out it's parameters, and `prim`'s parameter's at iteration. What I see is that the larger `toTrain` network's parameters change during training, while `prim`'s do not. Below is the training code. Is there a way to fix this?

```
numRuns = 10
function train()
    local crit = nn.MSECriterion()
    for i = 1, numRuns do
        toTrain:zeroGradParameters()

        local inData = torch.rand(1, 2)  --make some input/output data
        local outData = torch.rand(1, 2)

        local pred = toTrain:forward(inData)
        local err = crit:forward(pred, outData)
        local grad = crit:backward(pred, outData)
        toTrain:backward(inData, grad)
        toTrain:updateParameters(0.01)

        local bigWs = toTrain:getParameters()
        local primWs = prim:getParameters()

        print(bigWs) --the params for the big network change during learning,
        print(primWs) --but the ones for the primitive don't.
        print("------------------------------")
    end
end
train()
```

Answer (score 0):

`getParameters()` changes the memory location of the network's parameters, so any sharing is lost. See [this](https://github.com/torch/DEPRECEATED-torch7-distro/issues/33) for more details.

Comment: Can you post the code samples which solved the issue for you? I am having some trouble with weight sharing and haven't been able to understand what you've done exactly that solved the problem you had.